# Videoview replay feature not working in API level 17 and below

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to implement replay feature in the `VideoVew`. I has implemented successfully in the `API` level 18+ but not working in the below `API` level.
When i click on the replay button `VideoVew` freeze, does not start again.

```
 holder.videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer mp) {
                holder.replay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.pauseButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.playButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.mediaControls.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                removeProgressBar();
            }
        });



 holder.replay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateProgressBar();
                holder.imagePreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.replay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.videoView.seekTo(0);
                holder.videoView.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: share you replay click listener code

Answer (score 0):

call this on replay click

```
videoView.stopPlayback();
videoView.setVideoPath(newVideoPath);
videoView.start();
```

Comment: your video view is an item of you list view .. right?

Comment: yes it is in recyclerview. it's working perfectly fine in api 18+ but not working in below api levels